# Uploading pictures using Rack::Cors not working

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, voltrb

I am trying to upload some pictures from my controller to my bucket on an Amazon S3. I am using the ruby Volt framework. I need CORS  in order to do this, so I am using [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors). I have declared it correctly in my initializers/boot.rb file. This code was taken directly from the README.

```
Volt.current_app.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, it does not work correctly. When I try to post a picture to my S3, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/uploads. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Any idea as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you explain how your uploading the file to S3?

Comment: I am using a little bit of javascript to send the picture to the S3 bucket via XMLHttpRequest. I want to upload it from the browser, have the S3 respond with the url to the image, and save that url to the server. I am doing it this way so I don't have to upload the picture to the server to then upload it from the server to the S3 bucket.

Comment: This is probably an issue with the CORS configuration on AWS, not Volt. Have you [enabled CORS on S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) yet? You will need to do that on the AWS management console.